# Android: Optimize Design for different Screen Sizes

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen

I designed a .xml file, with a relative Layout where the distance between the elements is definied by the use of "dp". I thought this would work well, until I got a new Smartphone, with a much bigger screen than my old one had.
At the Top there is a TextView which should use 12% of the screen, than there is a ScrollView which should use 84% of the screen, and the last 4% should be empty.

This is the .xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.96"
android:background="@drawable/hintergrund"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Prüfung"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="437dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" > 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="293dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sf"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:text="@string/sf"
            android:prompt="@string/sf"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/odf"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="237dp"
            android:text="@string/odf"
            android:prompt="@string/odf"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ps"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <Spinner 
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:text="@string/ps"
            android:prompt="@string/ps"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<ProgressBar
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vorherige" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nächste" /> 
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you read this? http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: Yes, but it didn't solve my Problem, because both devices use the same folder.
It's the HTC Desire Z and the HTC One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your RelativeLayout with LinearLayout and i set weightSum to LinearLayout as 100. Last step is share it for its child as you want:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:background="@drawable/hintergrund"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Prüfung"
    android:layout_weight="12"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="84"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="293dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sf"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:prompt="@string/sf"
                    android:text="@string/sf" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/odf"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="237dp"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:prompt="@string/odf"
                    android:text="@string/odf" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ps"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                    android:prompt="@string/ps"
                    android:text="@string/ps" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Vorherige" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nächste" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Excellent!
This is a GREAT solution! Thanks a lot!
It works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using this textview as an example

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView5"
android:layout_width="293dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="16dp" />
```

the problem is you have hard width's ie. `android:layout_width="293dp"`

instead it should read `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

then add a margin to the right or where ever: `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"`

so this will make the width of you textview go all the way to the other side of the screen but indent the right margin `20dp` so you would see the space you want

Comment: The width isn't the problem.
The problem is, the height.

Comment: so then do the same thing for the height. The real issue is you should not be positions things in an absolute position and instead use wrap and fill content

Comment: But how else can I be sure, that the TextView on Top uses 12% of the Screen Size, the ScrollView 84% and the 4% on the Bottom are empty?

Comment: you cant which is why I said you should not be using hard widths/heights and be using wrap_content and match_parent in your layouts. it could be possible with margins like I said but there is not guarentee

Comment: The reason why I want it this way is the background image.
There is a small bar, where the first TextView is. Than there is a big area for the main content in the ScrollView, and the rest should not be used.

Comment: if you are using a background as your position markers then that is going to make it even more difficult to match up. you are better off using a plane background (take out the bars) and create the bars in the layout. using a background image to tell you where your elements should go is a very bad idea